# Why do some Kotlin files show lock icon?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The following code is from Kotlin-for-Android-Developers. The image of the project structure in Android Studio 3.0 is below.

Why do some Kotlin files show lock icon? Thanks!

And more, some Kotlin files have extensions .kt, and some Kotlin files don't have extensions, why?

[image]

Comment: The files ending with `.kt` contain more than just a class (or maybe not a class at all) while the files without the `.kt` contain just the class (like all Java files would do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a detailed description of the icons:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html

The open-lock means `public`. so you have a class in there which is public (public is the default visibility of Kotlin classes)